# What do cosmologists mean when they talk about "the running of the spectral index"?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

All I know is that the spectral index is related to the CMB, and that it has to be slightly less than 1 to favor inflation.

Answer (score 1):

The spectral index $n_s$ describes how the clumpiness of stuff varied on various scales just after cosmic inflation. The primordial power spectrum $P(k)$ of the fluctuations (where the wave number is $k=2\pi/\lambda$ with $\lambda$ being the physical scale), is predicted by many inflationary models to be:
$$P(k) \propto k^{n_s-1}.$$
If $n_s=1$, the fluctuations are *scale invariant*.

If $n_s$ is not a constant, but instead changes with $k$, that is if
$$\frac{dn_s}{d \ln k} \neq 0,$$
it is called a "running spectral index". And in fact it seems that that $n_s$ *does* chance with $k$ (see e.g. [Cherny et al. 2014](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4589)).

The term "*the running of the spectral index*" refers to the quantity $dn_s\,/\,d\ln k$.

Comment: Why are the fluctuations called scale invariant only if $n_s = 1$? In other contexts, power spectra are called scale invariant if the exponent of k takes any constant value ...

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question, @Dilaton. I think cosmology is the only place that uses the label "scale invariance" for a flat spectrum, not just any power law. Let me ask some clever people and get back to you.

Comment: Googling ["why is the primordial power spectrum called scale invariant"](https://www.google.dk/#q=why+is+the+primordial+power+spectrum+called+scale+invariant) led me to [this discussion](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-are-the-primordial-fluctuations-called-scale-invariant.315749/) that I don't have the time to read in detail right now, but maybe that helps.